# Trying to add a subquery to a join query

Tags: mysql, subquery

I have a query like this

```
SELECT
    tbl_products.*,
    GROUP_CONCAT(tags.name)
FROM
    tbl_page_collections_products,
    (SELECT page_collection_name as name 
       FROM tbl_page_collections 
       LEFT JOIN tbl_pages ON tbl_page_collections.page_id = tbl_pages.page_id 
       WHERE tbl_pages.page_name LIKE '%friends%') tags
    LEFT JOIN tbl_page_collections 
      ON tbl_page_collections.page_collection_id = tbl_page_collections_products.colID 
    LEFT JOIN tbl_pages 
      ON tbl_page_collections.page_id = tbl_pages.page_id 
    LEFT JOIN tbl_products 
      ON tbl_products.product_id = tbl_page_collections_products.product
   WHERE
    tbl_pages.page_name LIKE '%friends%'
```

The error I get is `Unknown column 'tbl_page_collections_products.colID in on clause` but I don't get that error when the subquery isn't there and that column exists in that table.

Is something conflicting?

Comment: A subquery as a column seems wrong to me somehow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tbl_page_collections_products is not in you subquery from clause.  Maybe this is what you want:

```
SELECT
tbl_products.*,
GROUP_CONCAT(tags.name)
FROM
tbl_products,
(SELECT page_collection_name as name 
   FROM tbl_page_collections
   ,tbl_page_collections_products
   LEFT JOIN tbl_pages ON tbl_page_collections.page_id = tbl_pages.page_id 
   WHERE tbl_pages.page_name LIKE '%friends%') tags
LEFT JOIN tbl_page_collections 
  ON tbl_page_collections.page_collection_id = tbl_page_collections_products.colID 
LEFT JOIN tbl_pages 
  ON tbl_page_collections.page_id = tbl_pages.page_id 
LEFT JOIN tbl_products 
  ON tbl_products.product_id = tbl_page_collections_products.product
WHERE
 tbl_pages.page_name LIKE '%friends%'
```

Comment: Sorry. SELECT
tbl_products.*,
GROUP_CONCAT(tags.name)
FROM
tbl_page_collections_products,
...